# Get SSL Certificate expiration date from client-cert.pem file stored locally in Android

Tags: android, delphi, ssl-certificate, firemonkey, indy

If I wanted to check the expiration date of a SSL certificate I can use `IdHTTP` connected to a `IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL`

```
IdHTTP1.IOHandler := IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1;
```

And then tapping into  `OnVerifyPeer`

```
function TForm1.IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1VerifyPeer(Certificate: TIdX509;
  AOk: Boolean; ADepth, AError: Integer): Boolean;
begin
    Showmessage(Certificate.notAfter));
end;
```

And finally doing a `IdHTTP.Get` to the server  I want to retrieve the  server certificate of, and this works.

BUT

I have a client certificate stored locally on my Android device that gets deployed with the App, how would I access the Certificate?

meaning how would I get the certificate loaded into a `TidX509` Object?
the constructor for `TidX509` requires a `PX509` which is then assigned to a pointer of a record `X509` so I am very lost in there

Comment: It depends on the type of certificate, and where it is stored.  The underlying OpenSSL library has functions for loading PEM formatted certificates from file or memory, for instance. You can't load a certificate directly into OpenSSL from Android's certificate store, so you will have to export the certificate to a file first, if it is not already.

Comment: @RemyLebeau , Thanks for the info, I see `idSSLOpenSSL` uses function `IndySSL_load_client_CA_file(const AFileName: String) : PSTACK_OF_X509_NAME;` but this returns a PSTACK_OF_X509_NAME but I would need a PSTACK_OF_X509_INFO if I am not mistaken? Because the X509_INFO record contains the X509 certificate? and there is no `sk_X509_INFO_new`  variable in `idSSLOpenSSLHeaders` excuse my  lack of understanding regarding the matter this is the first time I have used and worked with certificates

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Remy pointed out I just had to look how OpenSSL loads the Certificate from memory to get the certificate

but first the value that you get from reading the certificates `notAfter` is UTC Time value in String so you will need something like this

```
function StringUTCtoDATETIME(UTCString : String) : TDateTime;
begin
    if UTCString.Length = 13 then
    begin
        Delete(UTCString,UTCString.Length,1);
        Delete(UTCString,0,2);
        Insert(Copy(FormatDateTime('yyyy',Now),0,2),UTCString,0);
    end
    else
    begin
        Delete(UTCString,UTCString.Length,1);
    end;
    Result := EncodeDateTime(StrToInt(Copy(UTCString,1,4)),StrToInt(Copy(UTCString,5,2)),StrToInt(Copy(UTCString,7,2)),
    StrToInt(Copy(UTCString,9,2)),StrToInt(Copy(UTCString,11,2)),StrToInt(Copy(UTCString,13,2)),000);
end;
```

The value conforms to the ISO8601 standard which can be `YYMMDDHHNNSS` or `YYYYMMDDHHNNSS` so I just made provision for that the value returned will always be `YYYYMMDDHHNNSS`

And to get the value we load it into memory and work with it as Indy does.

```
function ReturnCertificateExpiryDate(const AFileName: String): TDateTime;
  var
      LM : TMemoryStream;
      LX: PX509;
      LB: PBIO;
begin
    LM := nil;
    try
        LM := TMemoryStream.Create;
        LM.LoadFromFile(AFileName);
    except
        SSLerr(SSL_F_SSL_LOAD_CLIENT_CA_FILE, ERR_R_SYS_LIB);
        LM.Free;
        Exit;
    end;

    if LM = nil then
    begin
        Exit;
    end;
    try
        LB := BIO_new_mem_buf(LM.Memory, LM.Size);
        if Assigned(LB) then begin
            LX := PEM_read_bio_X509(LB, nil, nil, nil);
            if LX<> nil then
            begin
                RESULT := StringUTCtoDATETIME(String(LX.cert_info.validity.notAfter.data));
            end;
        end;
    finally
        FreeAndNil(LM);
    end;
end;
```

And you also need to create a Context variable

```
var
    Context : TIdSSLContext;
begin
  Context := TIdSSLContext.Create;
  ShowMessage(FormatDateTime('yyyy-mm-dd hh:nn:ss',(ReturnCertificateExpiryDate(TPath.Combine(TPath.GetDocumentsPath, 'client-cert.pem')))));
end;
```